# Rounded radius in twitter boostrap navbar

Tags: css, ruby, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

There seems to be an odd border-radius of 4px on my navbar in my rails app using bootsrap 3 and I cant seem to get rid of it.

I've tried

```
  .navbar { border-radius: none}
```

I can't even edit the bootstrap css because I cant seem to find it. Any eloquent work arounds?

Here the HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <%= link_to "app", root_path , class: "navbar-brand" %>
 </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">

  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret">  </b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `none` isn't a valid value for `border-radius`. From the specs, the values of `border-radius` are lengths or percentages. See the  [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).

You want the following:

```
.navbar { border-radius: 0; }
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdgd4/)